# How install Action Text without Active Storage?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave, rails-activestorage, trix

I want to add action text to my app. But it also sets Active Storage. I already use CarrierWave, and don't need Active Storage. 
By the way, I do not need to upload files in the editor at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ActionStorage is a hard dependency for ActionText.

```
# rails/actiontext/actiontext.gemspec
# frozen_string_literal: true

version = File.read(File.expand_path("../RAILS_VERSION", __dir__)).strip

Gem::Specification.new do |s|
  s.platform    = Gem::Platform::RUBY
  s.name        = "actiontext"
  s.version     = version
  s.summary     = "Rich text framework."
  s.description = "Edit and display rich text in Rails applications."

  # ...
  s.add_dependency "activesupport", version
  s.add_dependency "activerecord",  version
  s.add_dependency "activestorage", version
  s.add_dependency "actionpack",    version

  s.add_dependency "nokogiri", ">= 1.8.5"
end
```

So you can either just live with it (ActionStorage and CarrierWave can co-exist) or use any the many other WYSIWYG alternatives or integrate Trix and Rails yourself.

Answer (score 3):

If you dont need to upload files at all then it should be reasonably easy to avoid adding ActiveStorage.

Go to `https://github.com/basecamp/trix` and follow their instructions how to setup Trix editor in Rails app. Just don't add `trix` to your Gemfile, but rather rely on what you have from Rails.

In case you would like to add files upload, you will need to play with overwriting `trix-attachment-add` event and setting files href to permanent URL, under which Trix can always find it.